# Error when submitting new entry via the Channel Entries API

Tags: channel

If member publish entry I want publish some info to another channel
I wrote extension, but it doesn't work and always I see 'An Error Occurred Creating the Entry'
I need help

This is my code

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



class Calladder_ext {

    public $name           = 'Call adder';
    public $version        = '1.0';
    public $description    = 'Add call when publish to channel';
    public $settings_exist = 'n';
    public $docs_url       = '';

    private $settings = array();


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     */
    public function __construct($settings='')
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $this->EE->lang->loadfile('calladder');
    }

    public function add_call($entry_id, $meta, $data)
    {
        if( in_array( $data['channel_id'], array(4,5,6) ) )
        {
            //prepare data
            // some code...

            $datap = array(
                    'title'         => $title,
                    'channel_id'    => 7,
                    'field_id_48'   => $phone,
                    'field_id_47'   => $name,
                    'field_id_50'   => $email,
                    'field_id_49'   => $comment,
                    'field_id_88'   => $entry_id
            );

            $this->insert_entry(7, $datap);

        }

    }

    private function insert_entry($channel_id, $data)
    {
        $this->EE->load->library('api');
        $this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
        $this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

        $this->EE->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $data);

        if ($this->EE->api_channel_entries->submit_new_entry($channel_id, $data) === FALSE)
        {
                show_error('An Error Occurred Creating the Entry');
        }
    }


    public function activate_extension()
    {

        $data = array(
            'class'     => __CLASS__,
            'method'    => 'add_call',
            'hook'      => 'entry_submission_end',
            'settings'  => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority'  => 2,
            'version'   => $this->version,
            'enabled'   => 'y'
        );

        $this->EE->db->insert('extensions', $data);

    }

    public function disable_extension()
    {
        $this->EE->db->where('class', __CLASS__);
        $this->EE->db->delete('extensions');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does it create the original entry? And does it get called multiple times? (does storing new entry with api call same hook again?).

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question so that it contains more than 1 sentence and a dump of your entire file. Explain what hooks you are using, what you have tried so far, and what you think might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank. ANd how I can add category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are you're missing a required field in that channel, or submitting some incorrect data. To find out why your entry is not being submitted, add this within your "if submit_new_entry is false" conditional:

```
print($this->EE->api_channel_entries->errors); exit();
```